# Linux : Pack PHP - MySQL app in RPM

Tags: php, mysql, linux, web-deployment, rpm

I have multiple **PHP-MySQL** applications which I ship to customers regularly. At each upgrade, I need to give them **PHP** scripts and **MySQL SQL** files. Things get messed up, usual problems are version mismatch or file permission mismatch or partial upgrades.

I have basic understanding of RPMs, and I can build a sample RPM if required. Host of the apps are Cent OS 6.2, **httpd** and **mysql-server**.

Should I pack my content in RPMs?

I see below benefits :

- Easy upgrades - # rpm -Uvh app.rpm
- Can host a repo online and my clients can # yum upgrade app
- More automated, less change for human mistakes.

Should I be doing this?

Comment: Another question: does the license agreement allow you to do so?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor , I hope it permits. As RPM is now used in many GNU/Linux distributions. see this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU/Linux_distribution

Comment: My Apps are open source. GNU/Linux is open source. RPM is open source. PHP-MySQL are open source. So it's permitted I guess...

Comment: To the close-voter: I think packaging and rolling-out should be consideres as a part of programming. So it is not completely OffT here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely should do so, if your target OS is RPM based.

Then you can add `httpd`, `php` and `mysql-server` as requirements and have exactly your content inside the RPM.

That's exactly what RPM is made for.

For the start, you might want to have a look at other RPMs to see how they deal with config files, documentation etc.

You as well might want to consider putting your application not under `/srv/...`, but under `/usr/lib/...` or `/usr/share/...` and have a specially crafted file under `/etc/apache2/vhosts.d/`, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks. I am marking your answer as selected. I was looking for an answer from someone who as done in already, so I can know common pitfalls, but this works anyway. :)